# Dynamic SQL Throwing Incorrect Syntax

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Good afternoon friends.  I have the below syntax, which I am left mind boggled over what the actual issue is.  SSMS presents me with an error of 'Incorrect syntax near 'Select' -- and it regurgitates the entire SQL String to me.

Can someone here point out what the issue is and how to remedy it please?

```
    Declare @rep varchar(max) = 'Habib', @startdate varchar(100) = '01/01/2017', @enddate varchar(100) = '03/31/2017'


SET @rep = CHAR(39)+CHAR(39)+@rep+CHAR(39)+CHAR(39)

Declare @sql nvarchar(4000) = 'Select * FROM OPENQUERY(sumSol,''Select 
        representative repName
        ,hiredate hiredate
FROM alpha ac
WHERE smellogram IN (''''1'''',''''3'''',''''4'''',''''5'''',''''6'''') 
AND id IN (Select id from frank)
               AND ((NOT ((holdingstatus = ''''13''''))))
               AND representative IN ('+@rep+')
               AND jbhiredate BETWEEN ('+ CHAR(39) + CHAR(39)
                               + CAST(@startdate AS NVARCHAR(500)) + CHAR(39) + CHAR(39) + N')
                               AND (' + CHAR(39) + CHAR(39) + CAST(@enddate AS NVARCHAR(500)) + CHAR(39) + CHAR(39) + N' '')'


PRINT @SQL
EXEC sp_ExecuteSQL @SQL
```

The error I get is

> Unclosed quotation mark after the character string

**EDIT**
This is the generated SQL

```
    Select * FROM OPENQUERY(sumSol,''Select 
        representative repName
        ,hiredate hiredate
FROM alpha ac
WHERE smellogram IN (''1'',''3'',''4'',''5'',''6'')
AND id IN (Select id from frank)
               AND ((NOT ((holdingstatus = ''13''))))
               AND representative IN ('Habib')
               AND jbhiredate BETWEEN (''01/01/2017'')  AND (''03/31/2017'')')
```

Comment: Lots of quotes.  Share the generated SQL

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - see edit - and thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to get lost with all the double quotes.  This is why I'll often use a PIPE to indicate a single quote, and then perform a simple replace.

Not tested

```
Declare @rep varchar(max) = 'Habib', @startdate varchar(100) = '01/01/2017', @enddate varchar(100) = '03/31/2017'

Declare @sql nvarchar(4000) = '
Select representative repName
      ,hiredate hiredate
 From  alpha ac
 Where smellogram IN (|1|,|3|,|4|,|5|,|6|) 
   and id IN (Select id from frank)
   and ((NOT ((holdingstatus = |13|))))
   and representative IN (|'+@rep+'|)
   and jbhiredate BETWEEN |'+ @startdate + '| AND |' + @enddate +'|'

Select @SQL = 'Select * FROM OPENQUERY(sumSol,''' + replace(@SQL,'|','''''') + ''')'

PRINT @SQL
```